# why do you have to put "virtual" into the base class instead of just using the "override" in children? in C++

Tags: c++

The headline pretty much says it all.
Why do you need to define in the base class that you will may override a function in the future?

This way you have to modify the base class if you want to derive a differently behaving version from it, and you havent thought about that particular function in the base to mark virtual.

As far as I know you solve such abstraction definition in java by using override which (although I only shed an eye on java so far) seems way more natural to me. Is this twist in c++ meant to enforce programmers to think ahead, or there is a technical reason why it works like this?

Comment: All functions are virtual in java, in c++ they are not unless you want them to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done so that the decision to make a member function virtual remains with the base class.

Deciding to make a function virtual has consequences in the design: if you make a function virtual, you must account for a possibility of it doing something differently. In contrast, you can count on a non-virtual function to remain invariant.

Allowing an `override` to force virtuality "from the outside" may break assumptions of the writer of the function. Besides, it would complicate separate compilation, because C++ compiler must do additional things for virtual functions that are not done for non-virtual ones, such as looking up the effective address from vtable or some other mechanism used to implement virtual dispatch.

In contrast, in Java all public and protected instance methods are virtual, unless you make them final. C++ did not take this route to let class designs without virtual functions at all. Java does not have this option because all classes inherit `Object`, while C++ lets you make your classes as light-weight as you wish.

Comment: Also, a major reason for not having functions `virtual` by default is efficiency - non-virtual functions don't need virtual table lookup, and can be inlined by the compiler. Java doesn't care about that, C++ does :)

Comment: @GoranFlegar Right. I tried to hint at that in the last sentence where I talk about "lightweight" classes. In general, offering virtual by default would go against one of C++ design principles, which is "you don't pay for what you don't use".

Comment: @GoranFlegar: The compilation model of Java has a pretty big effect too.  Java can compile code without virtual calls (and with inlining), and later if a derived class is loaded that has override, recompile the base class code.  C++ compilers do some devirtualization, but generally not speculatively like Java JITs do.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, didn't know that. But I guess you need JIT to be able to do it - basically you need to recompile not only the class, but all code that used one of the virtual methods of the class.

Comment: Also, just to prevent possible Java vs C++ discussions and which one is "better" - my comment was a bit hasty and some people that like Java may find it offensive. Offending anyone is not my intention. every language has its pros and cons: C++ has ultimate efficiency, but you pay a price in complexity and maintainability compared to Java.

Comment: @Goran: Yes exactly.  Whole program analysis including dynamically loaded modules is very powerful, but only possible with JIT.  (On the other hand, because JIT and especially speculative JIT gets run many times, it can't afford as in-depth optimizations, so AOT languages usually win on efficiency in the end)

Comment: @ Goran Flegar. Your on the right track, but it's nothing to do with inlining (which is a compiler thing) its to do with linking. Code you put in the header may, or may not be inline'd, functions which are non-virtual are called. Functions which are virtual are called via a lookup table known as the v-table. It's the difference between the compiler doing the call, the linker knowing what to call, and the address to call only being known at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If meta-classes make it into C++20, you can always use ["interface"](https://herbsutter.com/category/c/)
(watch the video)